# Size of JScrollPane is changing depending of JList content

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlist, gridbaglayout

In my `JPanel` I have got two `JScrollPane` which represent `JList`.

The problem is that when on starting program both lists are empty their size is the same. But when one of them has some values on the begining its size is changing.

How to avoid it?

I am using `GridBagLayout` but no matter which constraint I set it has no influence for my scroll pane.

This is how it looks like with empty JList.

[image]

And the example with some values in JList

[image]

```
gb.gridx = 1;
gb.gridy = 0;
gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
add(scroll, gb);

gb.gridx ++;
gb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
add(scroll2, gb);
```

Has anyone any idea how to set it correctly?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: you can to start to debugging an issue by using [JList#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when one of them has some values on the begining its size is changing. How to avoid it? I

When you create the JList you can use:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
```

This will allow the JList to calculate a consistent preferred size even as the data in the list changes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work work as expected. JList with values interpret in different way given RowCount quantity than empty JList. And also width of those lists is different.

Comment: @up94up, `also width of those lists is different` - read the JList API. There are two methods that allow you to control the width / height of the cell. One takes a String as a parameter and will calculate the width and height of a cell. The other takes an int as a parameter and just sets the width.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

scroll2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. The owner of a question or answer can [edit] it at any time.

Comment: Sadly it's not. I think that the problem stands in Jlist which is empty at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> JList#setVisibleRowCount(...)

Works fine for me on Windows 10 using JDK 1.8.0_141.

> width

Maybe the [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue-java.lang.Object-) method will work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListScrollPaneTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    int visibleRowCount = 8;
    String prototypeCellValue = "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm";

    String[] model1 = Collections.nCopies(20, "aaa").toArray(new String[0]);
    JList<String> list1 = makeJList(visibleRowCount, prototypeCellValue, model1);
    JScrollPane scroll1 = makeTitledScrollPane("Included Groups", list1);

    String[] model2 = {"loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong"};
    JList<String> list2 = makeJList(visibleRowCount, prototypeCellValue, model2);
    JScrollPane scroll2 = makeTitledScrollPane("Excluded Groups", list2);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    p.setOpaque(true);
    p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    GridBagConstraints gb = new GridBagConstraints();
    gb.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);

    gb.gridx = 1;
    gb.gridy = 0;
    gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(scroll1, gb);

    gb.gridx ++;
    gb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gb.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    p.add(scroll2, gb);

    return p;
  }
  private static <E> JList<E> makeJList(int rowCount, E prototypeCellValue, E[] m) {
    JList<E> list = new JList<>(m);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(rowCount);
    list.setPrototypeCellValue(prototypeCellValue);
    return list;
  }
  private static JScrollPane makeTitledScrollPane(String title, JComponent c) {
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(c);
    scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                       BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(), title));
    return scroll;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new ListScrollPaneTest().makeUI());
      f.pack();
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```